# Angular Route Params issue

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-components, angular-router

I have a couple of routes like below. My main/base app-routing looks like below:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'projects',
    loadChildren: () => import('../app/pages/pages.module').then(m => m.PagesModule)
}]
```

The PagesModule's Routing looks like below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':projectId/model', component: ModelComponent
    },
    {
        path: ':projectId/compare/:id', component: CompareComponent
    }
    {
        path: ':projectId/serving/:id', component: ServingComponent
    }
]
```

For Model component the url is correct, viz: localhost:4200/projects/123/model

With 123 as :projectId and 1 as :id, I want the URL for ServingComponent and CompareComponent be like:
localhost:4200/projects/123/serving/1
localhost:4200/projects/123/compare/1

What works:
navigation via HTML works like:

```
 <button [routerLink]="['../compare', model.id]">Compare</button>
```

Issue:
When I navigate from my TS file it doesn't work. Tried with below:

```
 this.router.navigate(['../compare', model.id]);
```

Can you please suggest what can be wrong? Do I need to modify my routes ? I wonder why TS navigation is not working while navigation works from HTML. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use relative path, you need to add `relativeTo` attribute like this:
`this.router.navigate(['../compare'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});`
(add also `model.id` param)

More details: https://angular.io/guide/router#specifying-a-relative-route

Comment: no problem, I'm glad I could help